# Why does DropdownButton have to come before the function named getDropdownBotton?

Tags: function, flutter, return

I was writing some code in Flutter and I could not understand why I have to write it this way.
If I want to return DropdownButton, why does the name have to come before the function `getDropdownBotton`? I mean, why do I have to write it and why doesn't this code work without it? Also, why do I have to write  when I return DropdownButton?

```
DropdownButton<String> getDropdownBotton() {
  return DropdownButton<String>(
    value: selectedCurrency,
    items: getDropdownItems(),
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        selectedCurrency = value;
      });
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: You have to return because the function is expecting that you return something of type `DropdownButton`... But why do you need `getDropdownBotton`? Are you calling it many times?

Comment: Isn't it a needed method name? if DropdownButton is a name of the type.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you write `<String>` for things like DropdownButton is because Dart (the language that Flutter uses) doesn't like to infer types. It can of course, but it's recommended that you declare it yourself.

As for why you have to declare the return type (the thing before the method name), again, Dart doesn't like to infer types. You can remove the type `DropdownButton<String>` and Dart will just infer the return type.

```
getDropdownBotton() { // Dart will now infer the type and secretly, the keyword `dynamic` is there to let it know it could return anything
  return DropdownButton<String>(
    value: selectedCurrency,
    items: getDropdownItems(),
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        selectedCurrency = value;
      });
    },
  );
}
```

`return` is required because you want the function to *give* you something, in this case, a `DropdownButton`. Without the keyword `return`, Dart will just execute the code and keep it all to itself (I know, greedy right?). With the return keyword, now the widget that calls this method will be able to get a Dropdown button to use from `getDropdownBotton`.

**P.S**: Your function is misspelled, it should be `getDropdownButton`.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I still don't understand why I need <String> in the same line as 'return'. Could you explain more about it? Also I do not have to include<String>, right? and the code still worked in the same way